# For what kind of a $\bf{Z}$-Module there can always be found a $\bf{Z}$-Module homomorphism s.t. the diagram commutes

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

What kind of a  $\bf{Z}$-Module should $A$ be so that the following condition holds?

If $B$ and $C$ are  $\bf{Z}$-Modules such that there is a surjective $\bf{Z}$-Module homomorphism $f : C → B$ and there is a $\bf{Z}$-Module homomorphism $g : A → B$ there can be found a $\bf{Z}$-Module homomorphism $h : A → C$ such that $f(h(a)) = g(a)$ for all $a ∈ A$.

What I have done:
I understand that $\bf{Z}$-Modules are just abelian groups and in order such an $h$ to be found it should be that $h(A) ⊂ f^{-1}(g(A))$. So I can focus my attention as assuming (without loss of generality) $C = f^{-1}(g(A))$ and $B = g(A)$.

Then the condition in the problem becomes (or implies? I am not sure):
$A$ is an abelian group such that if $B$ and $C$ are abelian groups and there are surjective homomorphisms $g : A → B$ and $f : C → B$ then $C/Ker(f)$ and $A/Ker(g)$ are isomorphic.

I could not move any further.

Comment: These are *projective* modules, and the theorem is that over $\Bbb Z$, the projective modules are the free modules.

Comment: Thank you. I see that the condition in the problem is actually the definition of a projective module. I am looking into the topic as of now. How do you think I can write an "answer" if this is a problem in a HW assignment?

Comment: You could, perhaps, give an equivalent condition on what it means to be projective. For example, a module is projective iff it is a direct summand of a free module. @Angine Seng is correct in saying that for the case of $\mathbb Z$, a PID, projective = free. However, this result takes some time and it would be unreasonable to prove it on homework - especially for someone who hasn't seen projectivity yet.

Comment: @paul blart math cop      Please note that I only need to show the statement for $\bf{Z}$, not all PID's. So, maybe there is a simpler way to show that the statement is equivalent to $A$ being a free abelian group without showing projective modules are free in the case of PID's.

Comment: I'm not aware of any easier way to do this with the special case of $\mathbb Z$, but it'll ultimately come down to proving that subgroups of free abelian groups are free.